# Removing all quotes from JSON file using PHP

Tags: php, json

I want to remove all double quotes from a JSON file using PHP.

The following code outputs all the variables to a JSON file named `example.json`:

```
$var_geoJSON = 'var geoJSON = ';
file_put_contents('jsonfun.json', $var_geoJSON);
file_put_contents('jsonfun.json', json_encode($geojson, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK), FILE_APPEND);
```

I was trying to get it to output something like this:

`var geoJSON = {...}`

Yet it outputs something like this:

`"var geoJSON = " {...}`

I am currently working with geoJSON to output to the open source leaflet.js mapping library, and the syntax requires that I have `var geoJson = {...}` instead of having `"var geoJSON = "{...}`.

I have tried using the `PHP` command `preg_replace()` replacing all the `""` with spaces, yet that still didn't work and it outputted the same thing with the double quotes.

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you extract your data from file?

Comment: @chumkiu don't understand, please elaborate.

Comment: Your code should not display what you say. How do you check the content of file?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `str_replace` function http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp example:
`$result = str_replace('"', '', $json)`

Comment: That didn't work... It still outputted the same thing. Do you know of any parameter in the command `json_encode()` that can answer my question?